# Parsing xml files without pretty print format

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to parse XML that has been pretty printed, but without the pretty print formatting. It seems all parsing methods I have tried so far however include the formatting. For example,

```
xml = etree.fromstring('<foo><bar>hello world</bar></foo>')
xml_str = etree.tostring(xml, pretty_print=True)

etree.tostring(etree.fromstring(xml_str))
```

returns

```
b'<foo>\n  <bar>hello world</bar>\n</foo>'
```

How do I get rid of the formatting and obtain the original XML message (`b'<foo><bar>hello world</bar></foo>'`)?

Comment: Maybe use `pretty_print=false` instead of `true`?

Comment: The xml has already been pretty printed. The pretty_print option is used in the example explicitly to create a small test example.

Answer (score 1):

```
xml = etree.fromstring('<foo><bar>hello world</bar></foo>')
xml_str = etree.tostring(xml, pretty_print=True)

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
etree.tostring(etree.fromstring(xml_str), parser=parser)
```

returns the expected

```
b'<foo><bar>hello world</bar></foo>'
```